# How to left pad text in C without knowing total length

Tags: c

I feel like what I'm asking is a really simple question, but here goes. I'm using a while loop to print the total length of various file sizes and I know that you can left align text by doing something like,

```
    printf("%5s ", file_size);
```

However, I don't know what the largest file_size is going to be and I need to print out all the file sizes by left aligning it to what file would have the most digits. As of right now I'm just assuming that the largest file size would be only 5 digits long. So my example output looks like this:

```
    File 1 Size:  46667
    File 2 Size:   5050
    File 3 Size:     21
```

The reason I need to do this is because the format required is to have two spaces after I print out File # Size:.

Comment: Your example shows *right* alignment, not *left* alignment. Maybe you can clarify / correct?

Comment: Did you mean "left pad"?

Comment: If you really do mean right alignment, then you have no option (other than guess a reasonable maximum) but to use a two-pass approach, where the first pass is for finding the maximum length of all elements.

Comment: Is `file_size` a *string*?

Comment: Do you really mean that you have the requirement to have: File<space><number><space>Size:<space><space><size>? If so, you don't need to do anything special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 options.

1, loop through all the files and find the longest one, and use that

2, choose a fixed size that will accommodate the max size you're willing to let them be.

3, make it dynamic, and keep the current "max width", and if your next one is ever longer, change the max width and redraw all the list.

(4) hybrid approach is to combine all that.  start with a good "likely width", keep the max width, and if any one goes over, then update max width and redraw all.

Comment: Yep, just going to go with your first solution. I was hoping that there might have been a way to use the flags in printf to do the job for me, but wanted to make sure. Thank you.

Comment: ok well please mark the green checkmark if this answer helped.